# How to get validation error messages in Lumen?

Tags: php, lumen

```php
public function register(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|string|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
        'first_name' => 'required|string',
        'last_name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    ]);

    try {
        $user = new User;
        $user->username= $request->input('username');
        $user->password =Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Registration Failed'], 403); 
    }
}
```

This is the typical response get:

```
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"status_code": 500
```

This doesn’t tell anything about the exact validation rule that failed.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function SaveContext(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    try{
        $rule = array(
            'userName' => 'required|string|max:4',
            'password' => 'required |string|max:4'
        );
        $messages = array(
            'userName.required' => 'User name is required.',
            'userName.max' => 'User name must not be less than 4 characters.',
            'password.required' => 'password is required.',
            'password.max' => 'password must not be less than 4 characters.',
        );
        $this->validate($request, $rule, $messages );

        return response()->json(
            AppResponse::Success($this->context->SaveContext((object)$request->all()))
        );
    }catch(\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $ex){
        return response()->json(
            AppResponse::Error($ex->errors())
        );
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```php
try {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username'  => 'required|string|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required|string|min:8',
        'first_name' => 'required|string',
        'last_name'  => 'required|string',
        'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
    ]);
}
catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $ex ) {       
    $errors = $ex->errors();
    return response()->json($errors, 422);
}
```